# converting a function into a php shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i'm new to php wordpress shortcode and i'm having issues regarding creating a shortcode which i can insert into my content. The function/shortcode that i'm creating has no input values. The issue is that when i'm using it in the content all content seem to disappear and nothing is shown form the function. The function works itself when i try to echo it but not through shortcode. What am i doing wrong

getHTML is calling another function, but no reason to add this since it works. Hoping for some guidance on what i'm doing wrong to make this shortcode work

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/simple_html_dom.php');

function getGames() {


$html = str_get_html(getHTML('http://URL',10));
    //$title = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '',$html->find("/[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h2/strong",0)->plaintext);
    //$manuf = $html->find("/[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong",0)->plaintext;
$table = $html->find("/[@id='matches_list']/",0);


$livescore = '';

            $livescore .= "<table class='match-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
             $livescore .= "<tbody>";

foreach($table->find("li") as $line){
    $game = $line->find("a/span/img",0)->title;
    if(  $game == "CS:GO" or $game == "Hearthstone" or $game == "Dota 2" or $game == "StarCraft II" or $game == "League of Legends"){

        $opp1 = $line->find("span.opp1",0)->plaintext;
        $opp2 = $line->find("span.opp2",0)->plaintext;
        $score = $line->find("span.score",0)->plaintext;



            $livescore .= "<tr class='margin-tr'>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-icon'>IC</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-home'>". $opp1 ."</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-score'>". $score ."</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-away'>". $opp2 ."</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-time'>22:00</td>";
            $livescore .= "</tr>";

        }

    }

                    $livescore .= "</tbody>";
            $livescore .= "</table>";



    return $livescore;
}


add_shortcode('getGames', 'getGames');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API):

> Shortcode names should be all lowercase and use all letters, but numbers and underscores should work fine too. Be wary of using hyphens (dashes), you'll be better off not using them.

Change your call to:

```
add_shortcode('games', 'getGames');
```

Then just call it via:

```
[games]
```